# Modify printf()s via macro to include file and line number information

Tags: c

I was just wondering if there is some macro-hack we can use, to alter existing printf() statements in a project.

```
/* file.c */
printf ("%s", strerror(errno));

/* After macro processing, this line would become */
printf ("%s %s %d", strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the preprocessor to modify standard functions, especially if others also will use the code. And by "others", that also includes you in a couple of months time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was just wondering how would we go about #undef and then redefining standard function.

Comment: You I don't think it can be done through a macro, since the macro won't understand usage such as `{ char buf[32] = "hello"; printf(buf); }`; it would try to append to the "format string" and fail, breaking the build.

Comment: ...seriously, my team had to work with some code that had headers with declarations of several variables as `extern int somevariable;`, and they were never defined. Lots of reverse engineering found a place where `extern` was #defined as no-op under obscure conditions before including said header. Wishes of cruel death for original authors were heavy in the air.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the caveat in my comment, you could do it using a [variadic macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro):

```
#define PRINTF_FL(format, ...) \
    printf(format " %s %d", __VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: if __VA_ARGS__ empty, this macro will be failed.`#define PRINTF_FL(format, ...) \
     printf(format " %s %d", __VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
 PRINTF_FL("hello");
}`

Comment: @jianxisun try ##__VA_ARGS__ to avoid an empty __VA_ARGS_ error when a comma precedes. Shall work with gcc, as explained in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
#define debug(fmt, ...) printf("%s:%d: " fmt, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

I used name `debug` instead of `printf`, because I don't think you should override standard functions. You could break something.

Use this like:

```
debug("This is debug no %d", 5);
```

To get output similar to:

```
program.c:12: this is debug no 5
```

(file: `program.c`, line: 12).

Answer (score 5):

And here is my "half penny".

### Function name & debug messages:

```
// debug mode, -DEBUG
#ifdef EBUG
    #define FNAME() fprintf(stderr, "\n%s (%s, line %d)\n", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define DBG(...) do{fprintf(stderr, "%s (%s, line %d): ", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
                    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);           \
                    fprintf(stderr, "\n");} while(0)
#else
    #define FNAME()  do{}while(0)
    #define DBG(...) do{}while(0)
#endif //EBUG
```

Use macro `FNAME()` to show just name of function & file/line, `DBG(text)` to show printf-like debug message with info about function name & file/line.

### And something that may be useful for coloured debug & error/warning messages.

#### In header file:

```
extern int globErr;
#define ERR(...) do{globErr=errno; _WARN(__VA_ARGS__); exit(-1);}while(0)
#define WARN(...) do{globErr=errno; _WARN(__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
#define WARNX(...) do{globErr=0; _WARN(__VA_ARGS__);}while(0)
// functions for color output in tty & no-color in pipes
EXTERN int (*red)(const char *fmt, ...);
EXTERN int (*_WARN)(const char *fmt, ...);
EXTERN int (*green)(const char *fmt, ...);
```

#### In C file:

```
int globErr = 0; // errno for WARN/ERR
// pointers to coloured output printf
int (*red)(const char *fmt, ...);
int (*green)(const char *fmt, ...);
int (*_WARN)(const char *fmt, ...);
/*
 * format red / green messages
 * name: r_pr_, g_pr_
 * @param fmt ... - printf-like format
 * @return number of printed symbols
 */
int r_pr_(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ar; int i;
    printf(RED);
    va_start(ar, fmt);
    i = vprintf(fmt, ar);
    va_end(ar);
    printf(OLDCOLOR);
    return i;
}
int g_pr_(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ar; int i;
    printf(GREEN);
    va_start(ar, fmt);
    i = vprintf(fmt, ar);
    va_end(ar);
    printf(OLDCOLOR);
    return i;
}
/*
 * print red error/warning messages (if output is a tty)
 * @param fmt ... - printf-like format
 * @return number of printed symbols
 */
int r_WARN(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ar; int i = 1;
    fprintf(stderr, RED);
    va_start(ar, fmt);
    if(globErr){
        errno = globErr;
        vwarn(fmt, ar);
        errno = 0;
        globErr = 0;
    }else
        i = vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ar);
    va_end(ar);
    i++;
    fprintf(stderr, OLDCOLOR "\n");
    return i;
}

const char stars[] = "****************************************";
/*
 * notty variants of coloured printf
 * name: s_WARN, r_pr_notty
 * @param fmt ... - printf-like format
 * @return number of printed symbols
 */
int s_WARN(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ar; int i;
    i = fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n", stars);
    va_start(ar, fmt);
    if(globErr){
        errno = globErr;
        vwarn(fmt, ar);
        errno = 0;
        globErr = 0;
    }else
        i = +vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ar);
    va_end(ar);
    i += fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n", stars);
    i += fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    return i;
}
int r_pr_notty(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ar; int i;
    i = printf("\n%s\n", stars);
    va_start(ar, fmt);
    i += vprintf(fmt, ar);
    va_end(ar);
    i += printf("\n%s\n", stars);
    return i;
}
```

#### In main():

```
if(isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)){ // make color output in tty
    red = r_pr_; green = g_pr_;
}else{ // no colors in case of pipe
    red = r_pr_notty; green = printf;
}
if(isatty(STDERR_FILENO)) _WARN = r_WARN;
else _WARN = s_WARN;
```

After that you will be able to use coloured output in case running in terminal and non-coloured in case of pipe. Functions `red` and `green` are analogues of `printf` for coloured output. Function `_WARN` used in macros to show user message and string for `errno`: `ERR` for case of errors (ends with `exit`), `WARN` — analogue of `ERR` but without `exit` and `WARNX` to show messages without `errno`.

Comment: what's the purpose of do { } while(0); ?

Answer (score 4):

to redefine the `printf` do not use `undef` just define the following `printf` macro in your header file

```
#define printf(MESSAGE,args...) { \
  const char *A[] = {MESSAGE}; \
  printf("%s %d",__FILE__,__LINE__); fflush(stdout);\
  if(sizeof(A) > 0) {\
    printf("::"); \
    printf(*A,##args); \
  } else {\
    printf("\n"); \
  }\
}
```

you can use your new `printf` macro in your code in this way

```
printf(); // it will print only the file name and the line number
```

or in this way

```
printf("debug message any data %d\n", 5);
```

Comment: This solution is good because it also works without any params. Compiles with both g++ and clang++, though clang++ generates a warning when the macro isn't passed any params and I'm not sure how to get rid of the warning: format string is not a string literal
      (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

Comment: VC++ compiler says: expected , or )  in args...  .

Answer (score 0):

Define below Macro MYPRINT. Include File name, Line number, Function name and \n

```
 #define MYPRINT(str,args...) printf("%s:%d %s() "str"\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,__func__, ##args)
```